# Is it possible to fork github repo with original issues?

Tags: github

1. This probably sounds weird but I would like to fork someone's repo with all the issues attached to it. I know I can fetch changes from the original(upstream) repo such as added files or changed files but I would like to sync issues from the original repo with my repo.
2. I tried to sync my fork with the upstream but I see that changes in Issues (upstream) are not reflected in my repo.
3. If that's not possible directly, is there a workaround?

**Update 1:** So far, as a workaround I found this tool which allows to clone (not fork) issues to your repo. Functionality is limited, but it works https://github.com/gatewayapps/kamino

**Update 2:** A few more details to clarify my question. I want to be able to:

1. Fetch changes regularly from upstream repo.
2. Edit GitHub issues (create new issues, add comments, label issues, add labels) without affecting upstream repo issues.
3. Merge upstream issues and my issues/edits.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

[GitKraken](https://www.gitkraken.com/) can do this for you out of the box by just cloning the forked repo and selecting GitHub as the issue tracker for the selected repo.

All issues will then appear on the sidebar.

Comment: Thanks @Casey! I'll have a look. Will it be possible to modify issues without affecting the original repo? For example, add labels, label issues, add comments?

Comment: @MZin By definition, changes to a fork do not affect the upstream repository. The only way they can affect each other is: A) The fork submits a pull request to the upstream repo and it is accepted; or, B) The fork is synced, pulling in the changes from the upstream repository.

Comment: thanks for explaining @Casey. Last question: can I merge upstream issues with local changes in issues? I understand this is possible when working with code (fetch changes and merge them with local changes). With issues, will it work the same way?

Comment: @MZin Issues do not change code, they only point out changes to be discussed. Issues can be linked to Pull Requests or other Issues via `#[id-number]` in their descriptions. A PR can even close an issue automatically by linking it with the text `Closes #[issue-number]`.