# Original repository issues on forked repository

Tags: github, gitkraken

I intend to work on an open-source project, I followed the below steps to start contributing according to this [instruction](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/contributing.html):

1- Fork the repository

2- Clone your fork of the repo from your GitHub account to my local disk

3- Install the development dependencies

4- Add the upstream remote.

5- Synchronize my main branch with the upstream/main branch

6- Create a feature branch to hold my development changes.

After doing these steps the issues that are defined in the main repository hasn't been shown in the forked repository. The issues in the main repository are several thousand but the forked repository shows zero. I followed the answer for this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67342500/is-it-possible-to-fork-github-repo-with-original-issues). But it didn't work for me.

**Question:**

My question is how can I have all issues and also pull requests of the original repository in the forked repository?

**Updates:**

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67342500/is-it-possible-to-fork-github-repo-with-original-issues), installing GitKrake and then cloning the forked repo and selecting GitHub as the issue tracker for the selected repo should solve the problem. I installed GITKrake and forked repo but the issue didn't be shown.

**New Question:**

Is there any way to see the issues without any other tools and directly on Github?
Can anyone give more detailed instruction on using GitKrake for seeing the issues of main repository on forked repository?

Comment: "But it didn't work for me." - this doesn't tell us anything useful. Do you mean you tried it and had a problem? Or that you can't use it for some reason? Without that detail, this question is simply a duplicate.

Comment: They suggested installing GitKrake and then cloning the forked repo and selecting GitHub as the issue tracker for the selected repo. I installed GITKrake and forked repo but the issue didn't be shown.

Comment: OK, then you could ask a question about that - maybe someone can help you get GitKraken set up correctly.

Comment: Some small notes: (1) GitHub issues are not stored in Git at all; they're highly specific to GitHub only (so I snipped one tag). (2) It's GitKrake**n**, with a final *n*, as in [the sea monster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kraken). That has its own tag (so I added that tag).

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to show all the issues of the main repo on your repo.